# What is (:+) called and what is it's function in this line of code?

Tags: ruby, reduce

totals = party.transpose.map { |r| r.reduce(:+) }

Here I am reducing a 2D array into a 1D array, and I'd just like to know more about (:+). I used it a few times in my code but I don't fully understand it, i.e. what it's called, when and why it's used

Answer (score 3):

```
irb(main):001:0> :+.class
=> Symbol
```

Its just a symbol containing the name of a method.

```
irb(main):004:0> 1.method(:+)
=> #<Method: Integer#+(_)>
irb(main):005:0> 1.method(:+).call(1)
=> 2
```

Enumerable#reduce and Enumerable#inject take a symbol, string or a proc and will call that method for each iteration of the loop.

```
[1,2,3].reduce(:+)
[1,2,3].reduce('+')
[1,2,3].reduce(&:+)
```

All three of these return 6. And they are short for:

```
[1,2,3].reduce { |sum, n| sum + n }
```

The reason symbols are most commonly used is that they are interned and thus use less memory then a non-frozen string attribute and they are also easier to type.

And finally with Ruby 2.4 you can just use [Enumerable#sum](https://blog.bigbinary.com/2016/11/02/ruby-2-4-introduces-enumerable-sum.html) instead:

```
[1,2,3].sum
```

Comment: "Most of the iterator methods in ruby can take a symbol, string or a proc and will call that method for each iteration of the loop." – Last time I checked (which admittedly was quite a while ago), there was exactly *one* method which takes the operation as a `Symbol` denoting the name of the operation to perform, namely `Enumerable#inject` (and its alias `Enumerable#reduce`).

Comment: @JörgWMittag yes, you're absolutely right. The enumerable methods take procs. Edited.